# CPU usage/ speed tradeoff when reading from a named pipe in python

Tags: python, asynchronous, cpu-usage, named-pipes

I want to read from a pipe asynchronously in python. The pipe is fed continuously from another process (a javascript process). I am using pipes for a matter of speed.

I don't want to loop and see if new lines are appended to the file, because it takes 100% of the CPU. I have tried `watchgod` `awatch`, but it adds a 300ms delay. My tradeoff is an `asyncio.sleep` of 1ms, it takes 10% of the CPU but adds 1ms delay.

```
import json
import time

import aiofiles
# from watchgod import awatch


async def amain():
    async with aiofiles.open('pipe_a', mode='r') as f:
        # async for changes in awatch('pipe_a'): # CPU=0% TIME=300ms
        while True:
            async for line in f:
                x = json.loads(line)
                print(f"pong: {time.time() * 1000 - x['time']} ms")
            await asyncio.sleep(0.001) # # CPU=10% TIME=1.5ms
            # await asyncio.sleep(0) # # CPU=100% TIME=0.5ms


import asyncio

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

loop.run_until_complete(amain())
```

What is the right way to get 0.5ms delay, and 0% CPU usage?

Answer (score 0):

Watchgod `awatch` is doing an async loop itself. So that's why it took 300ms as the delay of the default loop is 300ms.

On Linux, to watch file change, one must use [inotify](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html). There is an async library for inotify on python: [aionotify](https://github.com/rbarrois/aionotify). Waiting for file changes using notify does not block the CPU and catches the file event as soon as it appears.

The solution takes 0% CPU usage and a 0.5ms delay:

```
import asyncio
import aiofiles
import aionotify
import json
import time

watcher = aionotify.Watcher()
watcher.watch(alias='logs', path='pipe_a', flags=aionotify.Flags.MODIFY)

# Prepare the loop
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()


async def amain():
    await watcher.setup(loop)
    async with aiofiles.open('pipe_a', mode='r') as f:
        try:
            while True:
                _ = await watcher.get_event()
                async for line in f:
                    x = json.loads(line)
                    print(f"pong: {time.time() * 1000 - x['time']} ms")
        finally:
            watcher.close()


loop.run_until_complete(amain())
loop.stop()
loop.close()
```

Comment: Linux also has `epoll`, which is a better fit for "wait for this (virtual) file to have new data to read". `inotify` is something I think of as more for file system changes, not waiting for new data to arrive on pipe/socket "files". More portably, UNIX has had `poll` for decades, and `select` even before that, and any `async`/`await` event loop implementation should come with built-in support for waiting on a file descriptor to have new data to read (which will usually use the most appropriate/efficient API for the system it is running on).

Comment: See for example [this section of the `asyncio` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#watch-a-file-descriptor-for-read-events).